# access a Form1 public function from static class inside Form1

Tags: c#, class, static-classes

When writing this post i was checking all questions asked with related subject 
and couldent find a simple answer to this Newbs C# issue

i would like ... if i may , to have as much as it can be a well-explaind answer (Please!)

i made a public static class

```
        public static class MyLoadedBtmpToolBox
        {
            public static string FnameToLoad;
            public static bool PutLoadedByteArrInPicbox;
            public static string[] LoadedRefrnce;
            public static int SourceX_Loaded, SourceY_Loaded, RectWidth_Loaded, RectHeight_Loaded;

--->            public static int tst = Str2Int(LoadedRef[0]);

            public static byte[] LoadedByteArr;

        }
```

this calss as usually does by default, is within the main form i am using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using WindowsInput;

namespace MyScrCupTry1
{
    public partial class MyForm1 : Form
    {

            public static class MyLoadedBtmpToolBox
            {


              public static int testStr2Int = Str2Int("100");


            }




          public int Str2Int(string STR)
          {

            int strInt = Convert.ToInt32(null);
            if (isntEmpty(STR))
            {
                strInt = Convert.ToInt32(STR);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("theString " + STR + " is Null");
            }
            return strInt;

     }

}
```

i can't assing the `testStr2Int` a value , by using my public "helper Method" `Str2Int()` from the main form
i am Getting Error :

Error 1 ***An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property*** 'MyScrCupTry1.MyForm1.Str2Int(string)'  G:\RobDevI5-Raid-0\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\MyForm1.cs   95  45  MyScrCuptry1

What is the right way for accessing Main Form Public elemets from a static Class 
if it is possible / (not illegal)...

- **ReEditing**

after Those two answers ...

I tried to implement 
the code from first answer without expected results i guess i didn't know the right code structure with override OnLoad(..) thing ...

**BUT !** 
i have turnd the method `Str2Int(STR)` from public into **public static**

so now elements from the form itself still have access (i am surprised) to `Str2Int()`
and from the static Class I Can Access it too....

and its all thanks tp making it into static too ,

am i missing somthing else is there "hidden" drawback when changing Str2Int() from public into public static ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `static` code is that belongs to itself, rather than any other object.  For this to be true, when you set something as static, *everything* that depends on it must also be static!

This is what your error message is trying to tell you.  You are declaring something as static, but in the computation of that static, you are using something that is not static.  `Str2Int` is not tagged as static, so that is an immediate problem, and it's possible that `LoadedRef` is also not static.  I am half-sure you actually meant to use `LoadedRefrnce` there, in which case you're fine, but since you spelled nothing correctly I can't be sure!

Check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) for an explanation of the static keyword, also please make more of an effort to read up on [C# coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) - this makes it much easier for people to read your code when you ask for help like this!

Expanding upon the edits above:

The 'drawback' to making code static is that it pretty much instantly makes everything it is a part of untestable.  The idea behind unit testing is to have all of your code broken out into totally replaceable parts, so they can be tested separately and moved out separately (if need be).  By making a bunch of code static, you are essentially welding it to any other code it might be a part of.  In your own example, by making `Str2Int()` public static, everything that uses `Str2Int()` is now untestable!

Static code is, generally speaking, a vice that you should attempt to avoid as much as possible.  There are places where you can't, and if you are just starting to learn really the biggest focus is just getting something working.  But be ready to look back on this code and go cold at how you could've ever written something so bad in a few years, when you are more experienced and confident in your skills.

Comment: . Sorry i was working on some other issues you can have a look in my profile , but now that i see the answer you wrote, i mark as the correct answer and i do really thank you for the very helpful info , although I had a feeling as you implied,  that is why I tried to avoid it... but I hate instantiating non static (public) .... i don't know what is the right term in english in my language it's 2 words hate and for-free e.g. no reason ...just goggled it it's hatred (: i'll just better get used to it as quick as i can and in future codes you will see it implemented

Answer (score 0):

add `Form` object to static class, like this :

```
public static class MyLoadedBtmpToolBox
{
     public static Form MainForm {get;set;}

     public static int testStr2Int = MainForm.Str2Int("100");
}
```

and from the `Form` :

```
public partial class MyForm1 : Form
{
     private override OnLoad(..){

        base.OnLoad(...);    
        MyLoadedBtmpToolBox.MainForm =this;

     }
}
```

This design is fragile by itself, as you has to gurantee that `MyForm` property is intialized **before** it's used to call `..testStr2Int = MainForm.Str2Int("100")..`. 
So, considering that `testStr2Int` is public, may be intialization of it you can do in `Form` too and not in static class.

Comment: i have redited my post, don't know if you will come back to re read

Comment: @LoneXcoder: if you make Form's method *static* that means that from that method you can not access any Form member, which is not static.

Comment: thanks , i think i tried it and couldn't follow you i might had a bad syntax doing with what you didn't show in your code i will recheck on this ...had an error and too many squiggly lines ..i can now while reediting see the problem is it somthing to do with names of the form it self and decleration in `MyLoadedBtmpToolBox` right here in your example , unless MainForm is a reservedword is it or i just followd you too blindly as a parrot (: